# While loop to find if it's Weekday

Tags: php, loops, date, while-loop

Hi I want to create a `do while loop` that breaks when its a `weekday` but my loop isn't working and I'm not sure how to `break` the loop.

```
While($cur_date = date("w", $currentdate) == 0 || $cur_date = date("w", $currentdate) == 6 ){

}
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ you want to do that? Your script would be running for two days

Comment: Break out of the loop with [break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

Comment: Hi my project is an array with a startdate inside. I have a for loop that increases the date by a month every row. However I don't want the date to be a weekend so I'm trying to create while loop that can detect if the date is on a weekend and if so it adds a day to get to a monday(working day). I'm using a while loop so that if its a saturday, the loop carries on till the date is a monday then exits the loop , it should the change the value of the date in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Using the following loop, you can do what you wanna do

```
// Loop until date('w') = 0 or 6
while (!in_array(date('w'), array('0', '6'))) {
    // loop
    sleep(3600);
}
```